# Why is GDAL on Mac terminal not opening my .hdf-files from MODIS Terra/Aqua?

Tags: gdal, hdf

I try to get one variable raster data set from a multidimensional .hdf file using gdal_translate.

The type of file I try to open is from: https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD12C1.061/2021.01.01/

Why is GDAL on Mac Terminal providing me with the error:

```
ERROR 4: `XXXX.hdf' not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'XXXX.hdf'.
```

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Because your version of GDAL was not compiled with support for that format ("driver" in GDAL speak). Some formats are included with GDAL, so they are always available. For other formats you need to first install the library for that format and then explicitly include it when compiling GDAL.

For example, the [GDAL manual for hdf5](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/hdf5.html) says:

> Driver building This driver built on top of NCSA HDF5 library, so you
> need to download prebuild HDF5 libraries: HDF5-1.6.4 library or
> higher. You also need zlib 1.2 and szlib 2.0. For windows user be sure
> to set the attributes writable (especially if you are using Cygwin)
> and that the DLLs can be located somewhere by your PATH environment
> variable. You may also download source code NCSA HDF Home Page (see
> links below).

You are not saying how you installed GDAL. But a work-around could be  to use a version of GDAL that does support HDF5. For example, you can use the R terra package from CRAN, which includes GDAL with hdf5 support, I believe.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the format support for HDF5, and GDAL supports this file type. The files I am using are, apparently, HDF4 files. How can I include support for this filetype?

Comment: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/hdf4.html

Comment: Thanks. I installed the hdf4 library to my computer. How can I make GDAL use it? Uninstalling and installing with brew did not result in the format support (`gdalinfo --formats').